# How to compare files in 2 HDDs, find exact copies and different files and sync only what I need?

Tags: sync, file-management, music, comparison

**Problem:** I've got 2 external HDDs, which contains ONLY music files in many folders/sub-folders with some strict hierarchy (Artist/Band name - Albums name folders - song files), but different types (primarily .mp3, .ogg etc.), All the music files has filled tag information (like artist, album, year, album cover miniature etc.).
1st HDD is used frequently and constantly adding new material (like new albums or tracks). 2nd Hdd used as backup for 1st one, but manually. So, for now I'm sure, that some files in 1st HDD aren't in 2nd, but it's very hard to seek and find all of them (more than 250 Gb of data, >2500 folders, >28000 songs). And there is another problem (there is not only situation, when some files absent in 2nd HDD, but present in 1st or vice versa) - some songs are present in both HDDs, but in one of them the .mp3 id3 or other tag is more correct (latest updated by myself than the same file in other HDD).

**What i searching for:** is anyone had found the solution/tool, maybe, some kind of content managing tool or sync soft, which work closely with music file, which help me compare all folders and files between HDDs, find difference and choose what to sync, replace, delete.

**What I want in result:** complete copy in both HDD after managing with differences and choosing what to keep and what to replace.

If the solution is some kind of program - better it'll be for Windows 10 x64 or Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: Certainly not the answer, but a partial solution would be to generate md5/sha sums of each hard drive, 1 file per drive.  (Under  Linux) you can then use tools like sort, uniq and diff to identify duplicates and files which exist on 1 drive but not the other.

Comment: Sync Directories Tool in Total Commander worked and easier to handle than your Linux-based solution. So, I exactly don't know, if it works. But thank you for participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Total Commander](http://ghisler.com) file manager has **Synchronize directories** function (in menu **Commands**) which serves exactly this purpose and works well if corresponding directory trees have the same directory and file names on items (in your case: audio files) where data are equal.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfectly worked for me. At least, I can't find any better specialized software solution for now. I always know, that TC is powerful tool, but personally using merely quarter of it's functionality. +1

Comment: @maikayamaika – if this works for you, please accept the answer by adding green check mark, see [tour]

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm new to this ecosystem. Already done that.